# Development data set for feature engineering and data exploration

Tags: feature-selection

I dont hear this being talked about much:

If you want to engineer features and visually explore the data, should you do this on a development set separate from the training and test set?

If feature engineering and visual exploration is done on the training set (with cross-validation on this set to tune parameters) will this result in overfitting, and if so how badly?

What is a good size for this development set if necessary?